# Formatted Text in report Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2013.
I am generating a specifications writing database which involves the user inputting a number of items as data which is then incorporated into a report. The report structure is largely similar but there are something like 30 variants with small changes based on the data entered at the start.

Each report extends to around 7 pages whereas the data is only in the first 2 pages. The remaining pages contain standard clauses common to all the reports. effectively they are an instructional on using the products to which the specification report refers.

I now have a rather frustrating problem.

Is it possible please to set up a standard report using a rich text format. I have thought of using the bulk of the report as an image and incorporating this but it uses up lots of storage space. I have looked through the forum but cant find a scenario that really fits what I am looking for..

I almost want a really big text box that I can format in the same way as you would a word document. Not sure if this makes sense so if further clarification is required please ask. Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rich Text in Access, with the data stored in a Memo (Long Text) field: [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630)

I would set it up like this:

Have a table with one field per clause. This table has only one record. Fill out the texts directly in the table (or build a simple form for it, if you like).

In your record source of the report, add this table without any join (= cross join).

Then add all the fields to the report footer, height = 1 line, `Can grow` = True.

This will keep each clause together on a page. If you don't care about this, you can also use one huge field with all the text.